# Elegant way to look up and assign values from dictionary in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a pair of large dataframes, `taxi_origins` and `taxi_destinations`, with lat/long variables for origins and destinations. I would like to update a few observations (those with a DC airport as an origin or destination) with the lat and long contained in a small dictionary.

I was able to do this, but the result is very inelegant and feels like a lot of unnecessary repetition. What is the "elegant"/"correct" way to do this in base R and/or dplyr?

I tried various solutions using `merge` and `left_join` but came back to this base R approach. I feel like there has to be a better way, though.

```
airports <- data.frame(airport = c("DCA","IAD","BWI"),
                       lat = c(38.85334,38.95347,39.17971),
                       long = c(-77.04346,-77.44778,-76.66885),
                       taz = c(1511,2388,3036))

taxi_origins$ORIGIN_BLOCK_LATITUDE[taxi_origins$ORIGINCITY == "DCA"] <- 38.85334
taxi_origins$ORIGIN_BLOCK_LATITUDE[taxi_origins$ORIGINCITY == "IAD"] <- 38.95347
taxi_origins$ORIGIN_BLOCK_LATITUDE[taxi_origins$ORIGINCITY == "BWI"] <- 39.17971
taxi_origins$ORIGIN_BLOCK_LONGITUDE[taxi_origins$ORIGINCITY == "DCA"] <- -77.04346
taxi_origins$ORIGIN_BLOCK_LONGITUDE[taxi_origins$ORIGINCITY == "IAD"] <- -77.44778
taxi_origins$ORIGIN_BLOCK_LONGITUDE[taxi_origins$ORIGINCITY == "BWI"] <- -76.66885

taxi_destinations$DESTINATION_BLOCK_LAT[taxi_destinations$DESTINATIONCITY == "DCA"] <- 38.85334
taxi_destinations$DESTINATION_BLOCK_LAT[taxi_destinations$DESTINATIONCITY == "IAD"] <- 38.95347
taxi_destinations$DESTINATION_BLOCK_LAT[taxi_destinations$DESTINATIONCITY == "BWI"] <- 39.17971
taxi_destinations$DESTINATION_BLOCK_LONG[taxi_destinations$DESTINATIONCITY == "DCA"] <- -77.04346
taxi_destinations$DESTINATION_BLOCK_LONG[taxi_destinations$DESTINATIONCITY == "IAD"] <- -77.44778
taxi_destinations$DESTINATION_BLOCK_LONG[taxi_destinations$DESTINATIONCITY == "BWI"] <- -76.66885
```

Note--I know that I could call the lat/longs on the right side of the assignments with something like `airports[airports$airport=="DCA",]$lat`, but that would make each line even longer/uglier, so I just hard-coded them for now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? `dplyr::rows_update` will use a secondary table to update overlapping rows in the primary table, but to do so we'll need to align the column names.

```
library(dplyr)
taxi_destinations |>
  rows_update(airports |> 
                rename(airport = ORIGINCITY, 
                           lat = ORIGIN_BLOCK_LATITUDE,
                          long = ORIGIN_BLOCK_LONGITUDE),
              by = ORIGINCITY) |>
  rows_update(airports |> 
                rename(airport = DESTINATIONCITY, 
                           lat = DESTINATION_BLOCK_LAT,
                          long = DESTINATION_BLOCK_LONG),
              by = DESTINATIONCITY)
```